# Can't display file validation error message in codeigniter

Tags: file, codeigniter, validation

I have set form validation in my project. My all form validation is working but I can not display file input validation error message. The file is upload properly, it doesn't show any error when I upload an invalid file.  I try a lot of ways but anythings are not working.

**I give here only file uploading related code.**

**My controller**

```
    $config = [
        'upload_path'=>'./uploads/image/',
        'allowed_types'=>'jpg|png',
        'max_size' => '400',
        'overwrite' => FALSE
        ];

    $this->load->library('upload', $config);

    if(!($this->form_validation->run() && $this->upload->do_upload()))
    {
        $view = array('error' => $this->upload->display_errors());

        $view['admin_view'] = "admin/add_books";
        $this->load->view('layouts/admin_layout', $view);

    }
```

**MY model**

```
public function add_books()
{
    $data = $this->upload->data();
    $image_path = base_url("uploads/image/".$data['raw_name'].$data['file_ext']);

    $data = array(
        'book_name' => $this->input->post('book_name'),
        'description' => $this->input->post('description'),
        'author' => $this->input->post('author'),
        'publisher' => $this->input->post('publisher'),
        'price' => $this->input->post('price'),
        'quantity' => $this->input->post('quantity'),
        'categoryId' => $this->input->post('categoryId'),
        'book_image' => $image_path,
        'userId' => $this->session->userdata('id'),
        'status' => $this->input->post('status')
    );

    $insert_book = $this->db->insert('books', $data);
    return $insert_book;
}
```

**My view**

```
    <div class="form-group row">
        <label for="book_image" class="col-sm-2 col-form-label">Book image</label>
        <div class="col-sm-6">
            <?= form_upload(['name'=>'userfile', 'class'=>'form-control'])?>
            <div class="text-secondary">* Upload PNG, JPG format. Image should not be more than 400KB</div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-4">
           <div class="text-danger form-error"><?= form_error('userfile')?></div>    
        </div>
    </div>
```

**How it can be fixed?**

Comment: please explain: "is not working", Do you mean the validation of the file or the file uploading itself, or both?. You need to edit your question to explain better where you have a problem.

Comment: While you are answering @Vickel please show any validation rules you have set and what you consider a "valid file input" and where you expect it to be validated. Thanks

Comment: @Vickel Now you can see. I explain properly. Thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: @DFriend bro, have a look, please.

Comment: Do you have any other validation rules for other inputs?

Comment: Yes, I have other validation rules. These are working properly and show the error message. But file validation does not show anything, but it does not take invalid file.

Comment: I offered `50 reputations` for the correct answer. Anyone??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should separate `$this->form_validation->run()` and `$this->upload->do_upload()`

```
$view = array();
if($this->form_validation->run() == true){

    if(!$this->upload->do_upload('userfile')){
        $view['error'] = $this->upload->display_errors();
    }
 }else{
     $view['error'] = validation_errors();
 }

 if(array_key_exists('error', $view)){
      $view['admin_view'] = "admin/add_books";
      $this->load->view('layouts/admin_layout', $view);
 }else{
     //Insert the record
 }
```

Comment: Then how I write my `view code` to display the error message??

Comment: It shows me other validation errors but not shows the file error.

Comment: Have you add the file validation code in controller like this `if (empty($_FILES['userfile']['name']))
{
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('userfile', 'Document', 'required');
}`

Comment: Have you used `enctype="multipart/form-data"` in your form tag?

Comment: Yes, it is working, but it shows me all the error together. After seeing this picture you may get a better idea, https://imgur.com/a/AkLQXFQ. I want to show error like my other forms

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/192939/discussion-between-danish-ali-and-tahmid).